# Is there a way to trigger a 5V relay that is more robust than just feeding it with 5 V?

Tags: relay, components, esp8266

I'm using a ESP8266 to activate a siren. The siren is activated thru a 5V relay, and the 5V relay is connected to a transistor, the transistor is connected to a pin of the ESP8266. The power supply of the ESP8266 failed and it hung, in this state the pin went high and the relay was triggered.

I was wondering if there is someway to trigger the relay with some kind of code, not just voltage, as a safety mechanism to avoid activation due malfunction. My first idea was replacing the transistor with a cheap microcontroller, like an ATmega 88p.

Is there a more robust way for doing this?

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE. Schematics are better than words. There's a button on the editor toolbar and it's easy to use.

Comment: yeah, why would a transistor malfunction? Why would it malfunction *more likely* than a microcontroller, which is literally made out of thousands upon thousands of transistors? You should really share your circuit.

Comment: was it a MOSFET transistor? You can just put a pull down resistor (or pull up if it's PFET high side switch you have, but i doubt it) to make sure the gate of the N-channel MOSFET can't float high and accidentally latch on

Comment: The transistor is necessary to trigger the relay. The ESP8266 cannot source (or sink) enough current on its own. Depending on the siren power requirements, you might not even need a relay, just use a power-FET as the switch.

Comment: Also, what would power the mega 88? Wouldn't it be on the same power supply as the ESP8266 (which is also just a special purpose microcontroller)? (BTW, that would be EXTREME over kill, the tiniest of AVR tiny MCUs would suffice for most things). How does adding a second MCU in the chain make this any more robust? It only adds an additional point of failure.

Comment: what kind of a siren?

Comment: @KurtE.Clothier: agreed, another microcontroller is not going to help.  The simplest possible solution might be to just add a pull-down resistor on the GPIO that is just strong enough to overcome whatever is pulling up the pin on power-off.

Comment: seems to me that if the relay and the ESP share the same powersupply you're protected from false triggering due to power-supply failure.

Answer (score 7):

For critical systems, a failsafe circuit is used that has to be toggled continuously to activate the relay.

The GPIO pin is toggled in the main software loop (typically) after doing all the normal processing.  If the loop stops, the toggling stops and the relay is deactivated.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fWayFT.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

C1 blocks DC from the GPIO pin, C2 and R1 form a low pass RC filter that determines how long the output will stay active when the toggling stops (and removes the ripple from the AC component that is passed by C1 and rectified by D2).

You can simulate this using the above schematic or recreate in LTSpice or similar to see how the circuit works.

The values of C1, C2 and R1 are dependent on the GPIO toggling frequency.

Comment: Was about to suggest the same thing

Comment: A poor solution since it simply adds more components that could fail, and does not address the primary component failure ....the driver FET or transistor. The correct way is to use the WDT and driver sensing.

Comment: The concern was power supply failure or software failure on the ESP8266.  Using a solid state driver with fault monitoring instead of the relay addresses the issue of relay or driver transistor failure.  There are many parts available for automotive use that would fit the bill and are designed to fail open but also have short circuit and overcurrent detection

Comment: @JackCreasey The micro controller (and WDT) are more likely to fail than a non power-handling transistor. That's a nice solution, but passive components should always be the fail safe.